# C# CAML query to sharepoint returns all items in the list (instead of only ones that mach query value)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I have the following code in my app to pull details from a sharepoint list.

```
            string siteUrl = "http://SHAREPOINTURL";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UN", "PW", "DOMAIN");
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Licences");

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Account' /><Value Type='Text'>123456</Value></Eq></Where>";

        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(collListItem);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Filtered List: " + collListItem.Count.ToString() + "\n");
        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account: {0} \nLicence: {1} \nMAC: {2}\n", oListItem["Account"], oListItem["Licence"], oListItem["MAC"]);
        }
```

In the sharepoint list I have created multiple test items but every time I run the above code all items in the list are returned regardless of what I use for the camlQuery.

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong with this pretty new to C# and never touched sharepoint before this.

Edit1: updated with advice from below.

Edit2: simplified the code but still getting the same problem.

Comment: THis question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847269/caml-query-to-sharepoint-list-returns-entire-set/22849434#22849434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your last line of code:

```
textBoxReadShow.Text = Licence + "\t\t" + MAC + "\n";
```

You're truncating the text in the textbox each iteration of the loop.

You appear to want to be appending the text to the end of the textbox:

```
textBoxReadShow.Text += Licence + "\t\t" + MAC + "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted that problem but I the CAML query doesn't appear to be working and I cant spot any problem with it. At the moment it is just returning all items in the list.

Comment: It is late but if it is a `ViewXml`, shouldn't the start tag be `<View>`?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return the filtered items, in your case is returning all the items, correct? if yes, this problem is in CAMLQuery ...

I have read a small documentation(link below):

[Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx)

And I noticed the formatting ViewXml:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Account' /><Value Type='Text'>123456</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

try with this code:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Account' /><Value Type='Text'>123456</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

---

I have working using with caml.

some syntax to reflect:

```
camlquery.query = "<query> ..... </query>";
camlquery.ViewXml = "<view> ..... </view>";
```

SORRY MY BAD ENGLISH :S

Answer (score -2):

Remove`<Query>` and `</Query>`  from the CAML query.

Comment: That still returns all items from the list.